# Silverlight 4 - DataFrom CancelEdit does not work on Textbox with focus

Tags: silverlight, dataform

I have a Silverlight dataform bound to a model. Everthing works fine except when I edit a value in a textbox, do not tab out or click to another control and then hit the cancel button.

The cancel event is triggered properly all properties are set back except the one bound to the textbox holding the focus. The value of that textbox will be passed to model.

Lets assume I have a textbox with the original value of 100. I change it to 101, leave the cursor within the textbox and then click on Cancel. I would expect the value to change back to 100 as it does when I tab to another textbox before clicking on Cancel, but it stays at 101.

How can I force the dataform to reset the value of the current textbox on the Cancel event?

Answer (score 0):

On your model, implement `IEditableObject` There is an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.aspx) on the MSDN. What it boils down to is handling `IEditableObject.CancelEdit()`, which will be called via the DataForm when Cancel is clicked. You then simply revert your models data to whatever it is you desire at that point.

Comment: The interface is implemented and the event is handled if I first tab out of the textbox. The problem I am facing is that when I leave the focus on the textbox and hit cancel.

Comment: A workaround is to handel DboKmsQKundenViewDataForm_TextInputStart and DboKmsQKundenViewDataForm_EditEnded to restore the original value for this case.